# Can be made the fmt library that drake brings private?

Tags: drake, fmt

My workspace is a ros2-like workspace in which drake has been wrapped into a CMake package.

`drake` is pulling in a specific version of the `fmt` library which I am able to consume it. But the thing is I need to use another version of `fmt` that I have installed in my system and I would like to know whether there is a way to make that `fmt` library that `drake` brings private and not to expose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Drake uses `#include <fmt/format.h>` from its public headers, `fmt` must remain a public (not hidden) dependency of Drake.  There is no good way to hide such core dependencies that we use (`Eigen`, `fmt`, `spdlog`).

We try to stay within a few weeks of the most recently tagged `fmt` release so we hope that works for most users.  I suppose you need to use an older revision?

Instead of making `fmt` hidden, I suggest patching and rebuilding Drake to use your `fmt` that already exists.

The file that specifies which `fmt` Drake uses is https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tools/workspace/fmt/repository.bzl.  Within the call to the `github_archive` macro, add one new argument `local_repository_override = "/home/username/tmp/install",` pointing to a layout that has paths like `/home/username/tmp/install/include/fmt/format.h`.

If that solves the problem, we can look at exposing a CMake configure option for Drake to find a user-provided `fmt` and `spdlog`.

Comment: Oh all right, this is really helpful. Thank you for your time!